# Inserting hash symbol into Centos 6

Tags: keyboard, centos

I'm running Centos 6 64 bit. When I type the hash symbol I get the message:

```
Unknown key released
```

I have looked on various places online and tried multiple solutions;

- Pressing series of buttons (such as alt+3, control+hash) with no luck
- Changed my keyboard to the UK layout
- Pressed and held my keys to ensure they were not stuck down

None of these are working. Any solutions would help, if you need further information please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: are you looking for the escape character?

Comment: No, sorry if I didn't make that clear. I'm looking for the hash symbol (#).

Comment: are you using SSH or a local session?

Comment: I'm using SSH ( I believe) through the hosting company website.

Comment: and what is the ssh client OS?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's through Digital Ocean. I'm trying PuTTY now.

Comment: Windows, Linux, Mac? which of those is the client OS?

Comment: The server is running Centos 6? If that's what you mean

Comment: What's the OS on your PC

Comment: Windows, I just managed to get PuTTY working with hashes, looks like their web console was just a little bad at detecting buttons. thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I'll post an answer anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using a web interface, try using a desktop program, such as:

- PuTTY or KiTTY for Windows
- SSH for Linux and Mac

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a web interface, you are asking the web interface to communicate directly to the terminal for you. In doing so, they may interpret keys differently then your host machine (and you) would expect or know. This could be re-configured on your hosts end, but realistically you should simply use a common SSH client to meet common standards, and to avoid that whole headache to hear "no sorry we can't do that, just use a client" from your provider.

On Windows

- PuTTY
- SecureCRT
- MobaXterm

On *nix/OSX

- SSH support is baked in. Simply "ssh 127.0.0.1" replacing the ip address appropriately.